# Updating an Outlook.com event WITHOUT sending an email to all attendees

Tags: outlook-restapi

Anyone know if it's possible to update an Outlook.com event via the REST API and NOT SEND emails to all the attendees to the event?

I have a server that updates a calendar regularly. It just adds a line to the description. In Google, this works pretty nicely. Google will only re-send the invitation email to the attendees if the time changes. Outlook however will re-send the invitation every time *anything* changes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible in Outlook calendar. Because if you are the organizer of the meeting, almost any changes that you make is considered as an update and therefore, all the attendees will get notified. The only change that can happen behind the scenes is adding an attachment to the event. Attendees will not get the new attachment unless you want. Let me know if this is an option for you.